# How can I add arabic language in my android app

Tags: android, android-emulator, locale

I have built an arabic dictionary app , but my emulator doesn't have Arabic language so the text is not correctl y shown , what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Test your application on real device connected to the development machine.

Comment: it works on my android cellphone but not in eclipse emulator. I want to build an app which can work in any devices even if they wouldn't have the language.

Answer (score 1):

Try testing on the emulator for Android 3.0 and above. They fixed the arabic in these versions of the emulator.